# How to use NSAttributedString on SLComposeViewController

Tags: ios, facebook, sharing, nsattributedstring, slcomposeviewcontroller

I am developing an iOS application in which there is feature to send attributed text over facbook. I tried to pass attribute text or using subviews methods to SLComposeViewController's view but it won't helpful. I have reference application in which you can see the same feature. Find attached image of it.[image]